# Invalid LogIn Attempt

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the following code for login procedure.I kept the breakpoint at Login Controller and validateUser function  of service layer  to check where did I go wrong and I found out that I am getting the null value in dbUser object at ValidateUser function of service layer and it is showing invalid login attempt. Where did I go wrong? Am I missing something?

Controller View

```
 public ActionResult Login(UserLoginDTO userLoginDTO)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                userLoginDTO.Password = Helper.EncodePasswordToBase64(userLoginDTO.Password);
                UserLoginDTO user = userLoginService.ValidateUser(userLoginDTO);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    this.SignInUser(user, false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex);
            //throw;
        }
        return View(userLoginDTO);
    }
```

Model View

```
 public class UserLoginDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Service Layer

```
public interface IUserLoginService
{
    UserLoginDTO ValidateUser(UserLoginDTO userLoginModel);
}

public class UserLoginService : IUserLoginService
{
    private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    public UserLoginService(IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork)
    {
        unitOfWork = _unitOfWork ?? new UnitOfWork();
    }

    public UserLoginDTO ValidateUser(UserLoginDTO userLoginModel)
    {

        UserLogin dbUser = unitOfWork.UserLoginRepository.All()
              .Where(x => x.UserName == userLoginModel.UserName 
                      && x.Password == userLoginModel.Password)
              .FirstOrDefault();
        if (dbUser != null)
        {
            UserLoginDTO userDTO = dbUser.Convert();
            return userDTO;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Repository Layer

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    int Save();
    Task<int> SaveAsync();
    IRepository<UserLogin> UserLoginRepository { get; }
}

    private IRepository<UserLogin> _userLoginRepository;
    public IRepository<UserLogin> UserLoginRepository
    {
        get
        {
            return _userLoginRepository ?? 
                    (_userLoginRepository = new RepositoryBase<UserLogin>(_context));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are the password in the database actually stored in Base64? Because if you say you are getting `null` in `unitOfWork.UserLoginRepository.All().Where(x => x.UserName == userLoginModel.UserName && x.Password == userLoginModel.Password).FirstOrDefault();` that means that DB does not have a matching record for the user with this username and password.

Comment: Check the values of the `userLoginModel.UserName` and `userLoginModel.Password` from the ones in the DB. I think they do not match as `FirstOrDefault` will give you **NULL** if it is not able to find any match.

Comment: @trailmax What is the solution to this error?

Comment: Check what SQL statement is being generated, then run it on the database directly to see if it returns any results.

Comment: Is there a reason you are rolling your own functionality for storing usernames / passwords etc rather than using the built-in functionality?

Comment: @Sam Solution? Your data does not match your input. This is not an error, that's by default.